# Wordpress pagination issue - paged/page query var always 0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have a shortcode that displays games in a user's library and I'm struggling to get the pagination to work. This shortcode is added to the Woocommerce MyAccount area on a custom tab. It is initialized from the functions.php file like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_library_endpoint', 'add_game_library_content' );

function add_game_library_content() {
    echo '<div class="shopstore-toolbar clearfix"><button id="filter-btn">Filter       Library</button></div>';
    echo '<div class="libraryWrapper">';
    if( strpos( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/game-history/" ) !== false ){ 
        echo"game history";
    }else{
    echo do_shortcode('[my_library]');
    }
    echo '</div>';
    

}
```

The shortcode is here:

```
add_shortcode('my_library', 'library');

 function library( $atts, $content = null ) {
      extract(shortcode_atts(array(), $atts));
       
     if (is_user_logged_in()){
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         $current_user_library = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'library',true);
         $library = explode(',', $current_user_library);
         $library = array_filter($library);
                
         $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
         $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
                        'post__in' => $library, 
                        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                        'paged' => $paged, 
                        'nopaging'  => false
         );
         $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                   
         // The Loop.
         if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                             
                 $high_score = get_posts(array(
                       'post_type' => 'scores', 
                       'author' => $current_user->ID, 
                       'numberposts' => 1, 
                       'order' => 'DESC', 
                       'meta_query' => array(
                             array(
                               'key' => 'game',
                               'value' => get_the_ID()
                               )
                            )
                  )); 
                                       
              $play_count= get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'plays', false); 
              $plays = 0;
              foreach ($play_count as $p){
                 if($p['game'] == get_the_ID()){
                      $plays += (int)$p['plays'];
                  }
               }
                              
 echo '<div class="product-box"><div class="library-item">
       <a class="wishlist-remove" href="#" title="Remove from library"></a>
       <a href=" '.esc_url( add_query_arg( 'game', get_the_ID(), get_site_url().
       '/my-account/game-history/' ) ) .'">
       <img class="lib-img" src="'. esc_attr(get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full')) .'"/>
      </a>
    <div class="history">
      <div>Players: ' .esc_html( get_field('minimum_players', get_the_ID()) ) .' - '. esc_html( get_field('maximum_players', get_the_ID()) ).'</div>';
                                    
    if(isset($high_score[0])) {
        echo '<div>High Score: ' . esc_html(  get_field('score', $high_score[0]->ID) ).'</div>';
   }
                                 
    if($plays != 0){
        echo '<div>Play Count: '  .  esc_html($plays). '</div>';
    }
                                            
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url( add_query_arg( 'game', get_the_ID(), get_site_url().
         '/my-account/game-history/' ) ) .'" >Play History</a>
         </div>
         </div></div>';
                             
                                
    }//end while
                      
                          
    echo '<div class="score-links">';
          echo paginate_links( array(
                                'base'=> str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                                'total'=> $query->max_num_pages,
                                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                                'show_all' => false,
                                'type' => 'plain',
                              ) );
  echo '</div>';
                   
                           
      } else {
               esc_html_e( 'There are no games in your library.' );
     }


    // Restore original Post Data.
          wp_reset_postdata();
}

        }
```

I have tried using both 'paged' and 'page' query vars and the both return 0 or empty string. Using get_posts within the loop is supposed to be safe and to confirm I have run the code with that blocked out and it made no difference.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days, any guidence would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the `/game-history/` you are checking the URL path for? Is that the URL of your "my account" page, or are you trying to "extend" the URL of that? What do the actual URLs created in the pagination look like?

Comment: @CBroe The /game-history/ is testing for a different feature and unrelated. (I removed during problem solving and had no effect). The URL structure is 'tiltedTable/my-account/library/page/2/'

Comment: I can't find a documentation for the hook `woocommerce_account_library_endpoint` anywhere. Is this some extra WC plugin that provides the "library" feature? Or did you set up any URL rewriting yourself, to get the `/library/` part in the URL to work?

Comment: I'm not using a plugin for this, I did a custom URL rewrite. `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'library', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );`